# pd.to_datetime changes the values to 1970 which are not the correct dates

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column of the below type in dataframe.

```
MAT_DATE                                object
```

The values in this column are something like

```
42872   
42741  
...
...
```

How can I convert them to datetime ?
*These are essentially future dates.*
Using `pd.to_datetime()` converts them to year 1970

```
df['MAT_DATE1'] = pd.to_datetime(df['MAT_DATE'], errors='coerce')
```

If I use the excel to change to short date, it does well to convert the dates.
However I want to use it on the dataframe directly.

Answer (score 3):

Using the `origin` parameter of the [`pandas.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) that you are interested in and based on the days as the delta as @Wen suggested, this might work:

```
pd.to_datetime(df['MAT_DATE'],errors='coerce',unit='d',origin='1900-01-01')
```

Answer (score 1):

The number is days delta to offset date , the default for excel is offset is 1990-01-01

```
s=pd.Series([42872,42741])

pd.TimedeltaIndex(s,unit='d')+pd.to_datetime('1900-01-01')
Out[88]: DatetimeIndex(['2017-05-19', '2017-01-08'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

Comment: Thanks, but this gives me an overflow in int64 error while performing addition.
Any tips ?

Comment: @AsmitAdgaonkar no sure , what happen here, maybe you can adding pd.to_numeric firstly ?